# Flutter ipa file uploading failed: Asset Validation failed (File path too long)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, build, ipa

I have successfully made the ipa file but when I'm trying to upload it to test flight, it fails because of the following issue. I have tried two ways to upload the file, using Transporter application and via Xcode directly. Both failed because of the same issue.

> Asset validation failed (90947) Invalid package structure. 1945 file
> paths exceed the byte limit, for example:
> “Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/prodRelease/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/prodRelease/mergeProdReleaseAssets/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/devDebug/mergeDevDebugAssets/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/devDebug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/devDebug/mergeDevDebugAssets/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/devDebug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/devDebug/mergeDevDebugAssets/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/flutter/devDebug/flutter_assets/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/devDebug/mergeDevDebugAssets/flutter_assets“.
> Please reduce the length of the file paths and upload a new build.
> (ID: f2e82081-b17b-4a12-a97a-5b23f274dee1)

I'm using Flutter 3.3.10 and have tried it with 3 versions of Xcode (12.5.1, 13.4.1, 14.3.1)

Comment: why is there android folder in the path?

Comment: I don't know. That is what I am also trying to figure out. For some reason that android path is repeating itself infinitely.